# Missing functions in the Raspberry Pi V10 release

Tags: documentation, raspberry-pi

There are a few Mathematica users beside myself that are running it on a Raspberry Pi, and we found out it does not always perform the same as the Desktop version [[1]](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/08/01/wolfram-language-and-mathematica-updated-for-the-raspberry-pi/)[[2]](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/318410). During the testing of the prerelease it became obvious that some of the functions are too complex for the not-very-fast [[3]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/benchmarking-mathematica-performance-on-the-raspberry-pi)[[4]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28209/hardware-performance-metrics-for-mathematica) Pi. So Wolfram decided to omit them from the Pi release branch. Which functions are omitted is not currently documented, so I'd like to find out this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the list of all built-in functions with [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Information.html):

```
Information["*"]
```

However, this function prints its output to a special stream called [`$Urgent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Urgent.html) [[5]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15281/how-to-send-output-of-information-command-to-a-text-file). So to be able to manipulate the output, it needs to be redirected, for example to a text file. I ran this both on a desktop (OS X) version and a Raspberry Pi version of Mathematica V10:

```
infoFile = OpenWrite["output.txt"]
Block[{$Urgent = infoFile}, Information["*"]]
Close[infoFile]
```

And then compared the two function lists. The functions included only in the desktop version are:

```
Complement @@ (StringSplit[Import[#]] & /@ {"output.txt", 
    "pi-output.txt"})
```

> ```
> {Absolute,AllowKernelInitialization,Ascending,Associate,CelestialSystem,ConsoleMessage,
> CreateDatabase,Decimate,DeclareKnownSymbols,Descending,DisplayWith,DisplayWithRef,
> DisplayWithVariable,DrawEdges,DrawFrontFaces,EclipseType,EdgeCapForm,EdgeColor,EdgeDashing,
> EdgeJoinForm,EdgeOpacity,EdgeThickness,EmbedCode,EmbeddingObject,ExternalTypeSignature,FailedQ,
> FinishDynamic,\[FormalX]$,FrontFaceColor,FrontFaceOpacity,GraphicsColor,GraphicsHighlightColor,
> LineColor,LineOpacity,LunarEclipse,MoonPhase,MoonPosition,NewPrimitiveStyle,
> RectangleBoxOptions,RefBox,SelectionDebuggerTag,SiderealTime,Slice,SolarEclipse,SunPosition,
> Sunrise,Sunset,TemplateBlock,TimeDirection,UpdateDynamicObjects,UpdateDynamicObjectsSynchronous,
> $EmbedCodeEnvironments,$InterfaceEnvironment,$SynchronousEvaluation}
> ```

The Pi version also has some exclusive functions:

```
Complement @@ (StringSplit[Import[#]] & /@ 
   {"pi-output.txt", "output.txt"})
```

> ```
> {AssociationFormat,AssociationMap,BooleanStrings,CloudAccountData,CountDistinct,CountDistinctBy,
> DataForm,DeleteDuplicatesBy,ElidedForms,ExternalBundle,FailureAction,FormTheme,IndexBy,
> ItemAspectRatio,ListFormat,MissingBehavior,MissingString,PartBehavior,Pivot,Query,TimeFormat,
> URLBuild,URLDecode,URLEncode,URLExecute,URLExistsQ,URLExpand,URLParse,URLQueryDecode,
> URLQueryEncode,URLShorten,ValidateQuery,$CloudCreditsAvailable,$HTMLExportRules,$TemplatePath}
> ```

Comment: Something is incorrect here... Those functions are not exclusive to the Pi. They're all in my copy of v10.

Comment: @rm-rf Is this a bug in `Information` then?

Comment: When I evaluate `Information["*"]` in V10 on OS X, I find all the symbols in your Pi-exclusive list.

Comment: Any idea where `Decimate` came from?  I totally want to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: @shrx I don't know. I typically use `Names` for this, not `Information`.

Comment: @bobthechemist Decimation is just lowpass filtering followed by downsampling. I have a decimation function in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21706/5).

Comment: @rm-rf probably a lot more useful than what I was thinking about.  It doesn't look like this is a real symbol so I wonder why it's showing up in the OP's `Information["*"]` call.

Comment: Strange, I tried with `Names[]` but those functions are still missing. They are nevertheless included in the documentation but I can't evaluate them.

Comment: `Names["*"]` and `Information["*"]` give exactly the same list of symbols (after ``Remove["Global`*"]``), so there is no need to parse the output of `Information`...

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you have the relevant Release Id or version for your installation?